# Get the value of a defined variable

Tags: makefile, preprocessor

I am trying to write a makefile to automate the work of compiling, pushing the code to a server, and running the code all in one.

The problem is that I don't have a list of servers defined, and there are going to be other people using this makefile.

What I am trying to do is the following.

Let's say there is a code c code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define SERVER_NAME "Some Server"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   //Some random code
}
```

Is there any tool which I can use in the makefile, to which I will pass the C file along with all it's dependencies, and the tool will tell me what the (For lack of a better word) variable "SERVER_NAME" is defined to?

I need something of this sort

```
<Some tool> <c file initially created> <all include files> <any c specific switch>
```

and the output is something like

```
SERVER_NAME="Some Server"
```

I know I can always do a grep on the file and pull the variable, but I want to also take care of conditions like the following.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define SERVER1 //This might change to server2
#ifdef SERVER1
#define SERVER_NAME "Some Server 1"
#endif
#ifdef SERVER2
#define SERVER_NAME "Some Server 2"
#endif

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   //Some random code
}
```

I know that the C preprocessor is powerful enough to do this work, I just can't figure out what arguments or switches to pass to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gcc preprocessor option [`-imacros`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.0/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options) lets you scan the macros in a source file and ignore the rest of it.

Suppose your source file is named `foo.cc`:

```
#define SERVER1 //This might change to server2
#ifdef SERVER1
#define SERVER_NAME "Some Server 1"
#endif
#ifdef SERVER2
#define SERVER_NAME "Some Server 2"
#endif

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   //Some random code
}
```

Write another source called `serverReporter.cc`:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
  cout << "SERVER_NAME=" << SERVER_NAME << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Now build (with or without Make):

```
g++ -imacros foo.cc serverReporter.cc -o serverReporter
```

and run it.

(There may be a way to get the macro value without running the code, by means of an option like `-dD`, but I haven't yet gotten that to work.)

Comment: Nice answer, but the compiler changes as per the server selection. Some of my servers might be running something other than what the compiling system is running.

Comment: I will try out it none the less.

Comment: While the -imacros idea was good, it was not much of a use to me.
Though your comment did get me to research -dD, and it took me to -dM.
-dM did the trick, kind of, well it's good enough for me.

Comment: @Nitro: Great! I tried `-dM`, but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your header files do not declare any other constants (which may be a bit of a stretch for C++ code), you can compile a file like this:

```
// Comes from a header file
#define SERVER_NAME "server name"

const char compile_time_server_name[] = SERVER_NAME;
```

The resulting object file will have the string in its constant data section.  For example, if your target is ELF, you can use `objcopy` from binutils to extract this data:

```
objcopy -O binary -j .rodata server_name.o server_name.contents
```

The command `xxd server_name.contents` shows this:

```
00000000: 7365 7276 6572 206e 616d 6500            server name.
```

Note the trailing NUL; you may have to remove that by further scripting.  It is probably a good idea to check that the boject file contains only one symbol in the `.rodata` section, perhaps using `nm`.